# Why DurationFormatUtils ignore year in format?

Tags: java, apache-commons, duration

I have this code:

```
return DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(2034430000000L, yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS)
```

the result is: `0000-00-23546_15:26:40.000`

why the year and days are 0 and so many days?

Comment: What language/framework/etc. is this from?

Comment: ...and what meaning do you think the month would have in a duration? For a duration from 1st Feb to 1st Mar, it is intuitively 1 month, no days; but from 1st Oct to 31st Oct, it is less than a month, but still longer than the first duration.

Comment: According to this it looks like Java: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DurationFormatUtils.html

Answer (score 5):

Because the documentation says so: [`DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DurationFormatUtils.html#formatDuration%28long,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29).

From the docs:

> This method formats durations using the days and lower fields of the format pattern. Months and larger are not used.

The reason is that when you are talking about durations, how long is a month?  How long is a year?  A month is a variable number of days, as is a year.  Now if these durations are anchored, such a thing *can* make sense; in these cases these are what Joda-Time would call periods.

But in general, a duration is just a number of milliseconds, so months and years really do not make sense.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz thanks for the original edit of the link; I had to expand the answer, though; hope you get credit for the edit.

Comment: Absolutely no problem, I don't mind. I'm glad the answer improves, no matter who does that. +1 BTW.

Comment: @Ray: Yeah, you are right. I see know. sorry for this basic question

Comment: No need to apologize for asking.  It is easy to forget to look at the docs.  I probably should have had a smiley in my answer. :)